# Compass is not watching changes and my SCSS is only compiling when I stop compass watch and start it again

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, compass

I am looking to build a website with Foundation using SASS though I am encountering an issue where my SCSS only compiles after I compass watch and not during. Here are images to make it a little more clear:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMINX.jpg

The first image shows I have not put ANYTHING in the app.scss file so obviously it does not detect changes.

In the second image I have input some CSS in the app.scss file and it still should compile and be spotted by compass and log it. I saved it using the hotkey and nothing shows up in Git that I have changed anything.

**Here I use CTRL-C to stop Compass Watch and then start it again!**

In this third picture changes have been detected after I restarted Compass Watch. So for me to get compass to detect changes and compile, I need to restart it after every chunk of code I do a day.

The fourth picture shows that the CSS I input into app.scss has been compiled into app.css - both files in different folders and have different extensions obviously.

I can give more details if requested

The versions for Zurb-foundation, sass and compass I have installed are:

compass-1.0.0.alpha.13
compass-1.1.0.alpha.3
sass-3.4.5
zurb-foundation-4.3.2

I have tried reinstalling each of them and installing them in different orders. As you can tell I tried an older version of compass but to no result. (I am not actually sure if those two compass files are colliding, I thought the lastest one would always be noticed and the older one would be completely ignored.

They're all the latest versions. I used gem update to make sure.

Thanks

Comment: As an aside Im speaking to OP via Facebook as I know him personally and it seems that this is *not* an issue with Foundation or Compass, but rather a problem with his git setup, I'll post an official answer when Ic an

Comment: OK it seems OP has a problem with his compass config, but I don't know enough about compass to help him out. Issue is basically that Compass is not compiling his SCSS unless he restarts it.

Comment: Compass is being a pain so as suggested by Dan I will switch to Sublime text as it compiles scss too. Originally I was using Brackets.